# How to update large JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

The server sends me a data as JSON to descripe a product. A product consists of properties and nested arrays of properties, up to 4 level deep. In the Frontend the user can update deep nested values. Do I need to keep track of the path an then reconstruct the whole JSON object for my updating POST call? Or is there a more elegant way to do it? Or is the design of the backend service bad?

**data as JSON**

```
{
  "productId": 10,
  "features": [
    {
      "id": 45,
      "name": "Customization",
      "productOptions": [
        { 
          "id": 1, 
          "color": ["red", "green"],
        },
        { 
          "id": 2, 
          "slogans": [
             {"id": 32, "name":"Thank You"},
             {"id": 33, "name":"Thanks a lot"},
          ],
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**input to edit slogan**

```
<input data-id="32" type="text" name="slogan" />
```

**edit JSON to send back to the server**

```
const update = {"id": 32, "name":"Thank You so much!"}

// update slogan array
solgansUpdateIndex = slogans.findIndex(obj => obj.id == 32)
slogans[solgansUpdateIndex] = update

...

// update whole object for the updating POST call

{...data, //updateTree}
```

Comment: Please note that JSON is a string. If the data is in JS, it's just JS objects/arrays/etc.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what do you mean?

Comment: It's not a big deal, but it's good to know. `const data = { ...` is not JSON. https://www.benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: If you are trying to update the data stored in the db then is the backen who must handle that not the front changing the json. the backen must provide an endpoint to update each entity class

Comment: There are many ways that the back-end programmer could write an update API.  What you should do is to, first, *decode* the JSON into a JavaScript data structure.  Then, modify that data structure.  Finally, and if this is the way their API is designed to work, you *encode* the data structure back into JSON format and send it.  Never try to write code which manipulates a JSON-formatted string as a string:  "treat JSON as a black box." Trust that the magic encoder/decoder ring will do its job properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to send the whole object back to the server. What you should do is send a set of ids that uniquely identify which field should be updated.

Example: Let's take your data where productId is 10 and featureId is 45

You can create a controller in the backend such as `updateProductSlogan(int productId, int featureId, int sloganId, String/Slogan newSlogan).`

And then what this endpoint should do is get the corresponding slogan from your database with a query, using these ids and update that slogan with value of **newSlogan** param.

Note: If only field that contains slogans is the features field you can also hardcode that and change the method to `updateProductSlogan(int productId, int sloganId, String/Slogan newSlogan).` in which you will fetch the features property with no need to use an id for.

Comment: Yes, that would be a much more "sensible" way for the back-end designer to construct an update API.  It would be unwise to simply "let the client send back the whole thing and all you do is store it." (That trusts the client too much, and would be extremely difficult to debug.)  But, I've seen plenty of APIs out there with "unwise designs."